# Programatically determining file "size on disk" in advance

Tags: c, windows, winapi, diskspace, filesize

I need to know how big a given in-memory buffer will be as an on-disk (usb stick) file before I write it. I know that unless the size falls on the block size boundary, its likely to get rounded up, e.g. a 1 byte file takes up 4096 bytes on-disk. I'm currently doing this using *GetDiskFreeSpace()* to work out the disk block size, then using this to calculate the on-disk size like this:

```
GetDiskFreeSpace(szDrive, &dwSectorsPerCluster, 
                 &dwBytesPerSector, NULL, NULL);

dwBlockSize = dwSectorsPerCuster * dwBytesPerSector;

if (dwInMemorySize % dwBlockSize != 0)
{
    dwSizeOnDisk = ((dwInMemorySize / dwBlockSize) * dwBlockSize) + dwBlockSize;
}
else
{
    dwSizeOnDisk = dwInMemorySize;
}
```

Which seems to work fine, **BUT** *GetDiskFreeSpace()* only works on disks up to 2GB according to MSDN. *GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()* doesn't return the same information, so my question is, how else can I calculate this information for drives >2GB? Is there an API call I've missed? Can I assume some hard values depending on the overall disk size?

Comment: tip: It's a "round up to next multiple". You can use blocks = (MemorySize + (BlockSize-1)) % BlockSize; a bit shorter.

Comment: This of course assumes stuff about how much room a file holding N bytes will need on the file system in question. Sure, it will probably need N bytes for the data, but a file also has meta-data, that needs to be accounted for. The size of the meta-data might vary a lot with the file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN only states that the `GetDiskFreeSpace()` function cannot report **volume sizes** greater than 2GB. It works fine for retrieving sectors per cluster and bytes per sector, I've used it myself for very similar-looking code ;-)

But if you want disk capacity too, you'll need an additional call to `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()`.

Comment: That'll teach me to read the documentation more closely! I've just tried the code on my hard disk and it seems to work just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The size of a file on disk is a fuzzy concept. In NTFS, a file consists of a set of data elements. You're primarilty thinking of the "unnamed data stream". That's an attribute of a file that, if small, can be packed with the other attributes in the directory entry. [Apparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Resident_vs._non-resident_files), you can store a data stream of up to 700-800 bytes in the directory entry itself. Hence, your hypothetical 1 byte file would be as big as a 0 byte or 700 byte file.

Another influence is file compression. This will make the on-disk size potentially smaller than the in-memory size.

Comment: I'd also add sparse files to the exception list.

Comment: Sparse files don't appear spontaneously, you have to create them intentionally. OTOH, the attribute packing I described happens always, and file compression can happen if the directory (or disk) is compressed.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to obtain this information using the DeviceIoControl function and
DISK_GEOMETRY_EX. It will return a structure that contains the information you are looking for I think

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216(VS.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809010.aspx

Answer (score -3):

In actionscript!

```
var size:Number = 19912;
var sizeOnDisk:Number = size;
var reminder:Number = size % (1024 * 4);
if(reminder>0){
    sizeOnDisk = size + ((1024 * 4)- reminder)
}
trace(size)
trace(sizeOnDisk)
```